# User pay app not throught app store is ok?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am developing an pay English app. But in my country, people don't have 
favorable conditions for purchase through the app store. Just a small amount of the population have credit card or debit card to pay app in store. So I want to sell my app by cash or another way not through app store. But my app still avaible and can be download from appstore. I want to ask that what I do is legally. Apple accept it and they will don't ban my app from app store. And if Apple don't accept it, what can I do ? Thank you very much and sorry for my bad English

Comment: If distributing your app by yourself and not by App Store is what you want, then you have to enroll in Apple Enterprise Program. Check https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/

Comment: I want to make it clear. My app still avaible and can be downloaded from app store. If I  enroll in Apple Enterprise Program it wil be legal. Thanks for your answer.